# Response to Having trouble getting a handle on the wireless option

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, lan, firewire, texas-instruments

Please tell me if there is a way to: 1. switch the kernel driver in use, back to non proprietary, or disable the one now in use. 2. tell me how to actually get the wireless device/devices working. 
[image]

Now this is what I get when I follow the guidelines laid out here:[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

I get this in the terminal and cannot continue further. perhaps I can disable the kernel driver before attempting to repair?

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking maybe this isn't the correct driver and that's why it isn't working?

Comment: You are quite correct; you have the wrong driver.

Comment: I remember there was a list of drivers somewhere. I think perhaps at kernel.org?  If anyone has any advice for me...I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: See the duplicate at the top of the page? That's the better list.

Comment: I have began the steps laid out here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers However, I get this when I attempt to update or purge.

Comment: What is the response when you purge?

Comment: I got this here;                 http://i.stack.imgur.com/CzUZ9.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53718/discussion-between-demiurgetheartisan-and-chili555).

Comment: what I finally did was reinstall the OS and then followed the steps at the link you suggested. and everything worked out fine. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code or terminal output. This is hard to read and cannot be copy-pasted. Please copy-paste the text directly into the question and format it as `code block`.